# Drag, drop, sortable system using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

This is quite a complicated question so I am not looking for "full examples", but instead ideas of implementing a solution to my problem.

I am creating a drag-and-drop page where users can drag and drop tools into their workspace. This is currently working fine through the implementation of `draggable()` (jQuery UI).

However, the system is getting complicated with new features I am implementing:

- When dragged onto the workspace, the user can freely move the items around their page. However I would like the user to be able to drag items on top of other `divs`- and this dropped item should "morph" into this `div` (hopefully by using `append()`). This specific `div` that the element is dropped onto implements `sortable()`, so where ever the dropped element is placed should be its specific position on this sortable list.

  - EXAMPLE: If the `div` contains a number of dropped elements; lets say 5 items, if another item is dropped in between the 2nd and 3rd items, it should be appended to this `div` in that position.
- Secondly, any element that is appended to a sortable `div` should then have the ability of being dragged out of this sortable `div` (un-appended) and back onto the main area of the workspace (I have no clue of how to do this!) BUT it should still holds its ability of being sorted (list should still be sortable).

I am using jQuery + jQuery UI to complete this project and may use other javascript-based extensions if they can complete my desired outcome easily.

**Type of implementation I have at the moment**

This implementation is very unfinished.

```
    $("div.layout.lo-content > div.content").droppable(
    {
        drop: function(e, ui)
        {
            $(ui.draggable).appendTo($(this));
            if($(this).hasClass("ui-sortable"))
            {
                $("div.content").sortable('refresh');
            }
        }
    });
```

^^ when doing `sortable('refresh')` it breaks the system with error:

> Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on sortable prior to
>   initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'

The sortable list which the item is dragged onto:

```
$("div.layout.lo-content > div.content").sortable(
{
    opacity:0.7,
    axis:'y',
    start: function(e, ui)
    {
        $(this).children("div.ui-sortable-placeholder").css("height",$(ui.helper).css("height"));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using AngularJS with [ng-sortable](https://github.com/a5hik/ng-sortable).

It looks like it can do exactly what you have described.

> From readme
>
> 1. as-sortable can be added to the root element.
> 2. as-sortable-item can be added in item element, and follows
>      ng-repeat.

Here is a [DEMO](http://a5hik.github.io/ng-sortable/#/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `ui.draggable` you can use only https://jqueryui.com/sortable/ with the configuration parameter for connected lists.

It allows you to drag drop between different lists and also sort items per list.

API: http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/

Comment: Along with sortable, I would also like a way to allow the items be to dropped anywhere else outside of the lists. Is this possible?

Comment: I think you have to define each droppable area as a connected list.